# Should javascript comments be removed on the production bundle?

Tags: javascript, comments, production-environment, production

Are JavaScript comments considered a security risk when are in production code or is it a bad practice?

In a simple website, with JS + HTML + CSS without any framework or library, how can they be removed?

Comment: If you don't comment things that are security risks, then... no not really. A huge portion of the internet runs on unobfuscated javascript, and that's usually ok.

Comment: Your security should be maintained on the server rather than on the client, or relying on obfuscation on the client.

Comment: Security risk? Not unless you have some really interesting comments. But it's generally good practice to minify and bundle your script when possible, which would remove comments. There are many resources and help available online, and it's opinion which is "best", so I won't try to recommend one (I use visual studio anyway which does this for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments is not considered as security risk, but it's make your website heavier. If your website is heavy, and slow it can be usefull.

You can use [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) for minify, remove all useless things

Comment: It's not correct anymore. Since JS comments tend to have version numbers of the containing library, they could be security risks, as if there is any vulnerability that affects that specific version of the library, it makes easy to detect it by the attacker. From security aspect, all comments should be removed from production code.